# DBus configuration wild card

Tags: linux, configuration, dbus

I would like to add rules to my DBus configuration file (in /etc/dbus-1/system.d/MyConfig.conf) which include the wildcard character '*'

For example if I add the line `<allow own="*"/>` then any owner is allowed. If I replace this with `<allow own="com.MyDomain.MyName"/>` then this limits to a single name.

But what I would like is `<allow own="com.MyDomain.*"/>` but this does not seem to work.

Does anyone have a suggestion of how to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the information in the [dbus-daemon document](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-daemon.1.html)

From the manual:

> Complex globs like "foo.bar.*" aren't allowed for now because they'd be work to implement and maybe encourage sloppy security...
>
> <allow own_prefix="a.b"/> allows you to own the name "a.b" or any name whose first dot-separated elements are "a.b"

This covers what I was trying to achieve